# linux- out of free

Tags: linux, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [free memory in Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/121790/free-memory-in-linux)

I'm trying to determine if my server needs more memory.

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7993       7719        274          0        372       5866
-/+ buffers/cache:       1480       6513
Swap:        11617          0      11616
```

The cached is high and free is low (the server handles a lot of requests).  Is this indicative that the server could benefit from additional memory since all free memory is being used as cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's what Linux does: it takes up the bulk of free RAM and uses it as cache.  If processes require more memory, cache will be released for those processes.

The relevant line is the "-/+ buffers/cache" one, which indicates that you have 6.5 essentially free.  Also of note, you're not using any swap, so you've haven't hit a high memory usage situation.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) gives a lot of useful information how to interpret free output.

Comment: This was a really good article btw