# Which request is httpd2-prefork running?

Tags: apache-2.2, top

Hi my server is running low on memory from time to time

I assume apache is the problem. Is there a way how i can tell which http-url a httpd2-prefork from top is running?

Comment: Have you tried to analyze apache server-status page, atop, iotop?

Comment: Double check that you're [analyzing free memory correctly](http://serverfault.com/questions/85470/meaning-of-the-buffers-cache-line-in-the-output-of-free) if you're using Linux. It's a common misconception. You may also wish to put in a little more research effort; *"I think the problem is X, how do I solve for X"* can run people around in circles if you're incorrect.

Comment: serverstatus was my solution

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom log format logging both Process ID and URL. That way you should quite easily be able to find any errors.

First define the log:

```
LogFormat "%P \"%r\"" processid
```

Then insert it into your conf/vhost conf:

```
CustomLog /logs/processlog processid
```

Check documentation here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

Comment: arent logs written when the request has finished?