# free shows more memory used than top process total

Tags: linux, memory, centos6, memory-usage, top

**UPDATE:**

This was being caused due to a known issue with nss-softkn. See this article:
https://www.splyt.com/blog/2014-05-16-optimizing-aws-nss-softoken

---

When I run free -m from my centos 6.5 box I am seeing that I only have around 1400 mb of available ram, including the cache. When I do top, sort by memory and add up the processes I am only seeing around 1600 being used. I should have a LOT more free memory. This is happening on a couple of our boxes.

```
[root@db1 ~]# free -m
              total      used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7840       7793         47          0        287       1357
-/+ buffers/cache:       6148       1692
Swap:         7983          7       7976
```

top output

[image]

Here is a better way to visualize the memory consumed by the processes:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have about `1692m` in free memory according to Linux.

In the top "Mem" line it would seem like your memory is almost 99% (7793m / 7840m) but in reality you're only using about 78% of available memory. See also http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ for a more in-depth explanation.

---

**Free vs Top vs /proc/meminfo**

*Process memory*.
Adding up the memory used by processes in `top` and trying to match this with the used memory of `free` is going to give you a bad time. Due to `top` paging, you may not even get all the processes in this list a better way to go is to use `ps aux --sort -rss` to order processes by memory use.

*Disk caching*.
Linux is going to use the memory you aren't using to make things run much faster for you behind the scenes. This is noted in `free`'s "cached" column and is why you should look at the values next to "-/+ buffers/cache" for actual used and free memory.

*Kernel Slab cache*.
Kernel modules and drivers have a way to use your unused memory *too*. The "SReclaimable" is memory that you could use under memory pressure. There's a cool tool called `slabtop` that can identify how the kernel is this cache.

*Clearing caches*.

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` To free pagecache

`echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` To free dentries and inodes

`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` To free pagecache, dentries and inodes

**See also**

- [Meaning of the buffers/cache line in the output of free](https://serverfault.com/questions/85470/meaning-of-the-buffers-cache-line-in-the-output-of-free)
- [Explanation on Resident Set Size/Virtual Size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35129/need-explanation-on-resident-set-size-virtual-size)
- [Slab Allocation](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Slab_allocation)

Comment: The slab space was the problem.. I figured that out and added the link below, but since you took the time to detail it in the comment I selected your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue here. I needed to look at /proc/meminfo and see what the the kernel was caching as slab space. My problem was not understanding how much "free" memory top/ps/free said I had. It was the fact that these numbers were not adding up. The "free" command would tell me I had roughly 1692mb free but my processes only totaled up to about 20% of my total memory.

This article describes my exact issues:

http://blog.logicmonitor.com/2014/10/09/more-linux-memory-free-memory-that-is-not-free-nor-cache/

Comment: The link is dead. Here it is on webarchive: https://web.archive.org/web/20150430224646/http://blog.logicmonitor.com/2014/10/09/more-linux-memory-free-memory-that-is-not-free-nor-cache/

Comment: This is the current link from the logicmonitor site:
https://www.logicmonitor.com/blog/more-linux-memory-free-memory-that-is-not-free-nor-cache

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://blog.logicmonitor.com/2014/10/09/more-linux-memory-free-memory-that-is-not-free-nor-cache, I created a script that I called free (which I placed in a path ahead of /usr/bin in my .bash_profile) that produces useful results:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$result = `/usr/bin/free`;
print "$result";

if ($result =~ /cache:\s+(\d+)/)
{
 $mem = $1;
 $slab = `cat /proc/meminfo|grep SReclaimable`; $slab =~ s/[^\d]//g;
 print "Slab                  $slab\n";
 print "Actual Used        ** ",$mem-$slab," **\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are misreading the Buffers/Cache - there is > 6 gigs being used as memory cache as per the +/- Buffers/Cache line.   If this is needed it can be eaten into - as its not, the OS is using it to cache disk reads and similar.

Comment: Is that not saying I have 1692 free after buffers/cache are taken into the equation? 7793-(buffers+cache) = 6148 used.

Comment: Its saying you have used 1692 megs (7840-6148), and 6148 megs is being used as cache.